# Совместимость while True с другой частью кода

Tags: python, события, while

У меня есть 2 части кода. В первой - получение событий, во второй - инпут, который находится в цикле while True:

```
@account.message_handler()
    ...

while True:
    input = input('>')
```

Мне нужно чтобы код мог одновременно выводить полученные события, а также не закрывать строчку инпута. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить все это в разных потоках (процессах). правда ввод вывод в одну консоль одновременно не очень удобно. Или задумайтесь об архитектуре вашего приложения может что-то можно реализовать иначе.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) или [urwid](http://urwid.org/index.html)